# sql date in mmddyy format in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have this simple query that is driving me crazy.

```
select current_date as "TODAY" from table
```

except that I need the date to be in mmddyy format. so If I run it today it would be 030918.

I am using DB2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the date in a particular format, then convert it to a string, using `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(current_date, 'MMDDYY') as "TODAY"
from table;
```

Comment: Yes! thank you buddy! will accept this as answer in 8 minutes , when the ssystem lets me :) thanks again...so simple...

Answer (score -2):

select replace (convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 1), '/', '')